# How can I write-protect files on Skydrive?

Tags: onedrive

Is it possible to write protect (lock) files on **Skydrive** so they do not get deleted by accident?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can only [change permissions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/skydrive/change-access-permissions-faq) to a file or folder.

Comment: As far as I can see the permissions is only for sharing. Is there any way for me to "fake" write protection by removing my write permission on the files?

Comment: Since the files are on Microsoft's servers, I don't think you can go further than changing 'sharing permissions'...